# Displaying text box near to the label issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to display user lookup text box near to "css case health check champion text" . Problem here is it creates one more extra column.. so text box appears below the text. I applied few css. But still result is same.
[image]

```
   <div class="slds-form-element">
 <div class="slds-section-title">Select CS Case Health Check Champion </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <label class="slds-p-top_xx-small">CS Case Health Check Champion </label>
                <div class="{! v.showvalidation? 'slds-show':'slds-hide'}" style="color:red; font-weight: bold">
                    Please select the user before clicking Create records:
                </div>
                <c:GSS_customLookup  objectAPIName="User" IconName="standard:user" selectedRecord="{!v.selectedLookUpRecord}" />
            </div>
```

c:GSS_customLookup

```
 <div onmouseleave="{!c.onblur}" aura:id="searchRes" class="slds-form-element slds-lookup slds-is-close" data-select="single">

    <label class="slds-p-top_xx-small">{!v.label}</label>

    <!--This part is for display search bar for lookup-->  
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">

        <div class="slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
            <!-- This markup is for when an record is selected -->
            <div aura:id="lookup-pill" class="slds-pill-container slds-hide">
                 <lightning:pill class="pillSize" label="{!v.selectedRecord.Name}" name="{!v.selectedRecord.Name}" onremove="{! c.clear }">
                      <aura:set attribute="media">
                         <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.IconName}" size="x-small" alternativeText="{!v.IconName}"/>
                      </aura:set>
                  </lightning:pill>
            </div>
            <div aura:id="lookupField" class="slds-show">
                <lightning:icon class="slds-input__icon slds-show" iconName="utility:search" size="x-small" alternativeText="search"/>
                <span class="slds-icon_container  slds-combobox__input-entity-icon" title="record">
                    <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" iconName="{!v.IconName}" size="x-small" alternativeText="icon"/>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text"></span>
                </span>
                <ui:inputText click="{!c.onfocus}" updateOn="keyup" keyup="{!c.keyPressController}" class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input leftPaddingClass" value="{!v.SearchKeyWord}" placeholder="search.."/>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--This part is for Display typehead lookup result List-->  
    <ul style="min-height:40px;margin-top:0px !important" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid slds-lookup__menu slds" role="listbox">
        <lightning:spinner class="slds-hide" variant="brand" size="small" aura:id="mySpinner"/>
        <center> {!v.Message}</center>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfSearchRecords}" var="singleRec">
            <c:GSS_customLookupResult oRecord="{!singleRec}" IconName="{!v.IconName}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Annappa, you have been around for quite a while. You know how this site works. If you want to add detail to your post, use an **[edit]**. *That's not what comments are for*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check GSS_customLookup to see if it has a "label" attribute (most custom lookup components do). If not, the label goes inside the div, not outside:

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 ">
  <label class="slds-p-top_xx-small">CS Case Health Check Champion </label>
  <c:GSS_customLookup  objectAPIName="User" IconName="standard:user" selectedRecord="{!v.selectedLookUpRecord}" />
</div>
```

This is because slds-col creates a new "column", thus moving the lookup component to the right of the label.